# How to design table in MS Excel or MS Word with varying cell sizes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

How can I design a table in Microsoft Excel with varying cell sizes? I do not want to have the entire row as one size, but single cells as a specific size.

Comment: There is no way for that, in Excel all cells in a column has the same width. A workaround can be to decrease columns width and merge cells.

Comment: What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Why do you want to do it in Excel?

Comment: I want to create a table that has various sizes in cells pretty much different formats for different parts of the table.

Comment: why do you need to have it in Excel?

Comment: I don't necessarily, I figured this would be the easiest way.

Comment: You can have whole rows or whole columns of different sizes.  But by different, you're referring to both height and width different from surrounding cells, so more like a puzzle than a table?  If you need to do that in Excel or Word, you will probably need to create lots of extra rows and columns and then merge cells to create the odd blocks.

Comment: If misha256's answer isn't what you're talking about, add some kind of image that illustrates it (you can draw it in crayon on a napkin and snap a picture with your cell phone).

Answer (score 1):

The [Merge Cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Merge-and-unmerge-cells-f7850c71-8663-429a-9316-aa09fc161eaf) feature is the only way to do what you want.

Select the cells you want to turn into one big cell and click the *Merge & Center* button:

[image: Excel Merge & Center button]

After that you can change vertical and horizontal alignment as you wish.

If you need text to automatically wrap, format the merged cell like so:

[image: Excel cell word wrap]

Finished example:

[image: Excel merged cells example]

Comment: This is exactly what I was referring to, is there a way to set the inches of each cell, in the properties?

Comment: Awesome, we're on the same page. Um, yes and no. Excel is a bit dumb. For example, when you try set the row height (http://imgur.com/Pmp1hX7) on merged cells, it applies the height you specify to *each row* that makes up the merged cells. So you have to do maths. If you want the merged cell height to be *1-inch*, and it's made up of *4* rows, then you'll need to enter *0.25*.